# How can I programmatically navigate (not select, but navigate) a WPF TreeView?

Tags: wpf, treeview, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

We're trying to programmatically mimic the way the 'Up' and 'Down' arrow keys navigate around a `TreeView` from code-behind. (Note: Not simply selecting items, but mimicking arrow-key navigation.)

Specifically, our use-case is one of our `TreeView`'s `HierarchicalDataTemplates` has a `TextBox` in it, which of course steals all keyboard activity when focused.  But since this is a single-line `TextBox`, we want to basically have it ignore the 'Up' and 'Down' keys and instead pass them to the underlying `TreeView` to be processed there.

To do this, we subclassed the `TextBox` and are intercepting the 'Up' and 'Down' keys in the `OnPreviewKeyDown` override as follows...

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Up:
        case Key.Down:

            // Swallow the key
            e.Handled = true;

            // Get the navigation direction
            var direction = (e.Key == Key.Up)
                ? FocusNavigationDirection.Up
                : FocusNavigationDirection.Down;

            // Perform the navigation
            MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction));

            break;

        default:
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            break;

    }
}
```

This technique works great when the `TextBox` is in a `ListBox`'s `DataTemplate`, but does not work if it's in a `TreeView`'s `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Again, don't confuse this with simply selecting items.  We already know how to programmatically do that by binding a `TreeViewItem`'s `IsSelected` property to our ViewModel or manually walking the visual tree to get to the `TreeViewItem` we want. I'm specifically asking about *navigating* around the `TreeView`, duplicating what the 'Up' and 'Down' keys do.

For instance, if an earlier sibling has its children expanded and you press up, it goes to the last child of that sibling (or its child's children if it is expanded, etc.)  If the  earlier siblings children are collapsed, then it goes directly to that sibling.  There's additional rules if they are visible or enabled, etc.

We have also tried explicitly setting the focus to the `TreeViewItem` directly and performing `MoveFocus` on that, but that didn't work either.  Even tried calling that logic via a dispatcher to make sure the focus had actually changed.  Again, nothing.

We also tried playing with `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`, both on the `TreeView` itself as well as against a `TreeViewItem` but still, nothing.

Even if we have to do a `SendKeys`-type of thing, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF UI Automation framework probably has a way to do it.  But if that doesn't pan out, this project coded something to do it:

http://wpfsendkeys.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way is to use **TreeListBox** implementation of [Avalon Control Library](http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/), or similar to this (your own, for example). As you mentioned, you can apply your technique for **ListBox**, so I think it would be easy for you to apply it to **TreeListBox**, which is derived directly from **ListBox**.

Comment: Not sure (yet) if this is enough to get the answer (depends on what others come up with) but voting you up for the reference.  Very cool find!  Thanx!